# How is the problem NOVICE43 on Sphere Online Judge(SPOJ) related to Bell Numbers?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, math

Problem Statement :

> When I first learned backtracking I made a program to find all the
>   permutations of the English alphabets in lexicographically increasing.
>   Filled with elation I showed the program to Rohil. Rohil being someone
>   who likes to do stuff off the league was not impressed and gave me the
>   following variation of the problem help me to solve the problem:
>
> You have to find the number of permutations of length N(1<=N<=11) such
>   that at whenever an alphabet (say 'c' ) appears in the permutation all
>   the alphabets smaller than 'c' should have appeared before it at least
>   once. An alphabet is smaller than another if it appears before the
>   other in the English alphabet. ‘a’ being the smallest and ‘z’ being
>   the largest. For example when N=2 then aa,ab are the only valid
>   permutations and ba,bb is invalid since in ba all the alphabets
>   smaller than b have not appeared at least once before it. See example
>   for further clarification.
>
> Input
>
> Line 1: T(no. of test cases)
>
> Line 2: n1
>
> Line 3: n2
>
> …
>
> …
>
> Output
>
> Line 1: no. of such permutations of length n1
>
> ……
>
> …..
>
> Input: 2 2 3
>
> Output: 2 5

Link to the problem : [NOVICE43](http://www.spoj.com/problems/NOVICE43/)

I have read some online solutions to this problem and they say this problem can be solved using [Bell Numbers](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bell-numbers-number-of-ways-to-partition-a-set/). But I’am unable to decipher the relation between the two. Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is that these strings *just are* partitions of a set. If we start for example by taking the two strings over 2 characters and enumerating them:

```
12
aa


12
ab
```

We can start thinking of characters as *buckets* that the numbers go in. So the strings look like

```
a: {1,2}
b: {}

a: {1}
b: {2}
```

And if we forget the labels and ignore empty sets these look exactly like partitions of the set {1,2}, namely

```
{{1,2}}

{{1},{2}}
```

The restrictions on ordering are there to make sure we don't double count partitions, as `ba` represents the same partition as `ab`. (Exercise: prove that this is the case.)

So since each string represents a unique partition and the set of all such strings of length n represents all partitions (without repitition) of a set of size n, the size of these are the same. And the size of the set of partitions of a set of size n is just the nth Bell's number.